# Do "correspondence" and "correspondents" have the same pronunciation?

Tags: pronunciation

When I hear how *correspondence* and *correspondents* are pronounced, I can not distinguish which word it is, without any context.

Do these two words have the same pronunciation?

Comment: I'm sure you're hearing a T in 'corresponden**(t)**ce'. The reason why it happens; Epenthesis. Read [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/270748/106592) or [this one for more details](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/270182/106592).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such word pairs are called homophones, and yes, these two words sound the same.

Normally, I might vote to close a question asking about homophones, along with a mention that pronunciations can be looked up in a dictionary, so there's no need to discuss the matter here. I probably would have done that, had you asked about *pear* and *pair*, or *bare* and *bear*; however, in this case, I noticed that the pronunciations listed in the dictionary are **not** quite the same:

> **correspondent** (ˌkɒrɪˈspɒndənt) (presumably, **correspondents** would beˌkɒrɪˈspɒndənts)
>   **correspondence** (ˌkɒrɪˈspɒndəns)

The two pronunciations look similar, but not identical. So, your broader question is, "Can two words be considered homophones, even when their official pronunciations are not identical?"

I would say the answer to that question is YES, because there are certain letter pairs that are hard to pronounce, and therefore often get *elided*. Professor Lawler has written about elision in [this ELU answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96576/how-to-pronounce-twenty-correctly/96584#96584), where someone inquired about the word *twenty*. It's worth noting that one of the many letter pairs mentioned in that answer is *-nt*, which is the letter pair causing this homophonic instance. Because the *t* is hard to pronounce, both words are pronounced as though they ended with *-ence*, which causes the phenomenon you've been hearing.

Comment: I agree with all of this answer, except for the very last sentence.  Pronouncing the T isn't hard.  What's hard and unnatural is NOT pronouncing the T between an N sound and an (unvoiced) S sound.  There are quite a large number of words which end with -ance, -ence, -ants and -ents; and which are invariably pronounced with /ənts/, no matter what the dictionaries say.

Comment: Not quite right, I'm afraid. (Sorry, I had to downvote.) I'm pretty sure this is the same as [governance  - governan**t**s](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/270748/106592) or *once and wants*. There's an epenthetic T between the N and T. I've explained it in detail in [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/270182/106592). (I think it should be closed as a dupe of the questions i linked..??)