# Question about the pronunciation of "governance"

Tags: pronunciation

I looked the word *governance* up in dictionary and all dictionaries state its pronunciation is `[ˈgʌvənəns]` or `[ˈgʌvərnəns]`. However, I have several dictionaries that have audio and I can clearly hear they are actually saying `[ˈgʌvərnənts]`. The ending sound is the same as the word `its`. Is there a rule for this pronouncing behavior? Thanks.

### Update

Add two Youtube videos (the link include the time, you just need to listen a few seconds):

https://youtu.be/s-l2ldsy3Kk?t=122

https://youtu.be/M0e3AeqGLaQ?t=1299

Comment: In my speech (and, I think, most of the people around me) there is no difference between 'mince' and 'mints'. Except in careful speech, there is an epenthetic /t/ in "mince".

Comment: Wow, I don't know that! I always differentiate /s/ and /ts/. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: @ColinFine Does that apply to most (if not all) words that end with "ce"?

Comment: Just a learner: most words that end with _-nce_. Note: I speak British English. It may be different elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Colin Fine said in the comments beneath the question, words that end with *-nce* are prone to [epenthesis](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/270182/106592).

Most people tend to insert an epenthetic stop between *Nasal + Fricative* sequences

The reason is because the air comes out through the nose while articulating a nasal and as the nasal changes to a fricative—an oral consonant—the airflow must be switched from nasal to oral and should be stopped before articulating an oral consonant, so there is a brief period in which both the nasal and oral airflow are stopped, this is a brief oral stop, homorganic (same place of articulation) with the nasal.

[ˈgʌvərnəns] ends with a nasal+fricative so it's likely to be epenthesised to [ˈgʌvərnənts]

In most accents, *prince/prints, mince/mints, sense/cents* etc., are homophones.

<sup>Fricatives are /s ʃ θ/ and nasals are /m n ŋ/.</sup>